# System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []:

Tags: trigger

I am trying to invoke Lead assignment rule when ever certain criteria meets the trigger should fire.

But I am getting the following error :

> execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Update
>   failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id
>   not specified in an update call: []:

Can anyone guide me where I am donig wrong.Thanks in advance.
My Trigger:

```
trigger LeadAssignment on Lead (After insert,After update) {

    List<Lead> updateLeads = new List<Lead>();

    Lead newLead = new Lead();
    for(Lead l : trigger.new)
    {
        if(l.Status == '01-New' || l.Status == '50-Qualified')
        {
            AssignmentRule AR = new AssignmentRule();
            AR = [select id from AssignmentRule where SobjectType = 'Lead' and Active = true limit 1];

            Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
            dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId= AR.id;
            system.debug('dmlOpts***********'+dmlOpts);

             newLead.setOptions(dmlOpts);
           // updateLeads.add(newLead);

                    }

    }
    update newLead;
    system.debug('updateLeads************'+newLead);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to update `Lead newLead = new Lead()`, you didn't give it an ID so it doesn't know who it needs to update.
You would have to do something like `newLead = new Lead(Id=l.id)` inside the loop;

But in general, i think you need to bulkify your code. Currently you will only do the update on one lead, and it will be the last lead in the trigger.

Comment: Hi Dana Griff, Can you please guide me with code. I have tried newLead = new Lead(Id=l.id) inside the loop;but it is not working.

Comment: Please update the question so i can see what you did